# atomic variable with bitflags from struct

Tags: c, multithreading, struct, atomic

I have a single atomic variable which I read and write to from with the C11 atomics.

Now I have a struct which contains every flag like this:

```
typedef struct atomic_container {
    unsigned int        flag1       : 2;
    unsigned int        flag2       : 2;
    unsigned int        flag3       : 2;
    unsigned int        flag4       : 2;
    unsigned int        progress    : 8;
    unsigned int        reserved    : 16;

}atomic_container;
```

then I use a function to convert this struct to a unsigned int with a 32 bit width using bitshifts. and then write to it with the atomic functions.

I wonder if I can directly write this struct atomically rather than first bitshifting it into a unsigned int. This does seem to work but I am worried this might be implementation defined and could lead to undefined behavior. the struct in question is 32 bit wide exactly as I want it.

Comment: Most similar thing to what you're trying to do is an union but that way to use it is UB so AFAIK no, it can't be done as an atomic operation

Comment: It is already a 32-bit struct.  Unionise it with a 32-bit atomic int.  You might like to use whatever __packed__ pragma, or whatver your compiler has, but on all the 32-bit systems I've worked on, this is not necessary.

Comment: @MartinJames I never saw a problem with that (union.item1 then access value through union.item2) but strictly speaking is UB.